# Automate Ember.js application using Selenium when object properties are changed at run-time

Tags: java, selenium, ember.js, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am trying to automate an Ember.js application using Selenium+TestNg.

The drop-down in the application has only one object property id. However every time i refresh the Page id gets change and there is not pattern.
Eg: First time i open a page id=ember1398 and when i refresh the page same object id changes to ember1097.

I would be greatful if some one can guide me in overcoming this challenge. I am open to change tool/framework if necessary.

Comment: can't you use xpath to locate elements?

Comment: only id property is displayed and that too changes at run-time and since there is no pattern of changes creating xpath is not possible

Comment: can you post the outline of code...?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Ember. We work with lots of third party applications to integrate with them so we do a lot of automated testing using selenium, when they use ember we hit this issue which means we cannot test the code as well as we can with other partners. I'm sure there are good reasons to use Ember but being able to test it easily with Selenium isn't one of them. There was a bug opened on this in ember but it got closed.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11834

Until ember fix this my recommendation would be to use a different JS framework that's built to be tested by third parties using something other than JS and or the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is [EmberJS](https://emberjs.com/) enabled element so some of the attributes e.g. *id* will be dynamically generated. As an example, `ember371`, `ember382`, `ember393`, etc. In these cases you won't be able to use the full value of the `id` attribute to locate the element. As an example, consider the following element:

```
<input placeholder="" id="ember32" class="ssRegistrationField ssEmailTextboxField ember-text-field ember-view" type="email">
```

The value of the value of the `id` attribute will keep changing dynamically, everytime you access the *AUT(Application Under Test)*. Hence to **locate** the element, the solution is to construct **dynamic** [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as `visibilityOfElementLocated()` as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.ssRegistrationField.ssEmailTextboxField.ember-text-field.ember-view[id^='ember']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'ember') and @class='ssRegistrationField ssEmailTextboxField ember-text-field ember-view']")));
  ```